# Additional information about potions and decotions in Witcher 3

Tags: the-witcher-3

In short, I'm looking for more descriptive descriptions what each potions and decotions is doing.
Plus points if someone knows how to get this kind of information in-game.

For example, instead

```
Maribor Forest - Accelerates the generation of Adrenaline Points.
```

I'm looking for

```
Maribor Forest - Accelerates the generation of Adrenaline Points for x%.
```

Comment: I believe the best way to do this is to create a default mod and get a hold of some of the pre-packaging XML files. I'll give it a shot at some point, if noone beats me to it.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, I couldn't find in any guide the actual rate for Maribor Forest's accelerated generation. That is a bit weird.

This can only tell me that **the acceleration is somewhat standard**. Maribor Forest has 2 other improved versions (Enhanced and Superior) but they both have the **same acceleration rate except the duration is higher**. The same accelerated speed I observed with other potions that affect health points for example (like Swallow). The accelerated rate is the same but **the duration is always the one thing that improves with better potions**.

Here are the guides I usually use:

http://gaminggix.com/the-witcher-3/witcher-3-potions-list-all-tiers-with-description/

http://uk.ign.com/wikis/the-witcher-3-wild-hunt/Potions